# Problem: BOS Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

So I'm having a very annoying problem: Paladin Danse won't give me the next Brotherhood of Steel quest (the one that has me go to the prydwen, via vertibird), and he won't have cognitive conversation, just a repetitive menial response, including "I'm busy right now." I've done Haylen and Rhys's missions for 2 and a half hours. Can someone help me?

Comment: Ben has the right answer for you. I'm sure you aren't far from the next mission, don't worry.

Answer (score 11):

Progress with the main story quest to get ahead with the Brotherhood of Steel. Before that, you can only repeat Rhys' and Haylen's quests over and over.

**[Possible Spoiler]** When does the next quest appear?

> Near the end of the quest [Reunions](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reunions) (credit to DCShannon)

Comment: I had the same issue as described, i thought it was a glitch. This is the correct answer. You need to progress in the main story. It will be very obvious when you can get to the next mission.

Answer (score -3):

Ur suppose to kill Kellogg first. Then the Prydwen will come in to the commonwealth and you’ll get something on your radio. Tune to it and the quest starts.

Comment: No, you can definitely access the Prydwen LONG before killing Kellogg.

Comment: @Nelson you need to complete the main mission Reunions (and thus killing Kellog). When you exit Fort Hagen, there is the scene with the Prydwen arriving in the Commonwealth.